# Ruby regex or string manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I am trying to create a Rails app that takes in RSS feeds and displays news stories to a page.

When I get the summary for an article I save it to a string, however the summary for every single story has a lot of markup at the end that is unnecessary. For example:

```
The Miami Dolphins have suspended a defensive lineman after he allegedly touched women and then took an "aggressive fighting stance" when police attempted to arrest him, according to a probable cause affidavit.<div class="feedflare">
<a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:7Q72WNTAKBA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:gIN9vFwOqvQ"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"></img></a>
</div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~4/4W6duenqKrY" height="1" width="1"/>
```

The only line I want to keep in this is:

> The Miami Dolphins have suspended a defensive lineman after he allegedly touched women and then took an "aggressive fighting stance" when police attempted to arrest him, according to a probable cause affidavit.

I want to parse out everything including and after the `<div class="feedflare">` tag.

I was stumped on how to do this. If someone could please provide a ruby string manipulation method or a regular expression method that I can use to do this, I would greatly appreciate it. I have been stumped on this for quite a while, since I'm a novice to Ruby and regex.

Comment: Try to use nokogiri to parse this HTML.

Comment: parse it how? I already have this information stored in a string. I just want to get rid of all the markup after and including the feedflare tag. And how would I even do this using nokogiri? thanks for the quick response, I would appreciate any other insight you could shed on this problem

Comment: Is this in rails by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take a more close look and realize this simple ER expression is enough. Take a look too.

```
a=%Q[The Miami Dolphins have suspended a defensive lineman after he allegedly touched women and then took an "aggressive fighting stance" when police attempted to arrest him, according to a probable cause affidavit.<div class="feedflare">
<a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:yIl2AUoC8zA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:7Q72WNTAKBA"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:V_sGLiPBpWU"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:qj6IDK7rITs"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"></img></a> <a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:gIN9vFwOqvQ"><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=4W6duenqKrY:kemJFf3BScg:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"></img></a>
</div><img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~4/4W6duenqKrY" height="1" width="1"/>]

     a.gsub(/\<[^\>]+\>/m, "")
```

Comment: It kinda works. It has the potential to greedily find way too much or be tricked by a less-than in the desired content. `'1<2 <p>foo</p>'.sub(/\<[^\>]+\>/m, "") # => 
"1foo</p>"`

Answer (score 2):

You tagged rails, so I'm assuming that's what you're using.  Rails comes built with a great sanitization helper:

```
[6] pry(main)> HTML::FullSanitizer.new.sanitize('The Miami Dolphins have suspended a defensive lineman after he allegedly touched women and then took an "aggressive fighting stance" when police attempted to arrest him, according to a probable cause affidavit.<div class="feedflare">')
=> "The Miami Dolphins have suspended a defensive lineman after he allegedly touched women and then took an \"aggressive fighting stance\" when police attempted to arrest him, according to a probable cause affidavit."
```

There are a variety of methods to help with this, take a look at `strip_link` and `strip_tags` as well, [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html)